# How to get geographic coordinates from DBpedia for geotagged Wikipedia articles

Tags: r, sparql, wikipedia, dbpedia

I want to query all articles with a staff-entry and their geographical coordinates from the [German DBpedia](http://de.dbpedia.org/). Due to the fact that not many articles have a separate column with `lat/long` in the infobox, but are geotagged (see [WikiProject Geographical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:WikiProject_Geographical_coordinates)), I want to get the geotag, which are in the upper right corner of a Wikipedia article (if existing). Any ideas to get this information (if possible within R)?

Example code in R

```
library(SPARQL)

query <- "prefix  dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> 

SELECT DISTINCT  ?name
             ?staff
             ?lat
             ?long
             ?geometry
WHERE {
  ?place               rdfs:label ?name   .  
  ?place        dbpedia-owl:staff ?staff  .
Optional {  ?place      geo:lat   ?lat    . }
Optional {  ?place      geo:long  ?long   . }
Optional {  ?place      geo:geometry  ?geometry   . }  
}
LIMIT 100"

endpoint <- "http://de.dbpedia.org/sparql"
resultList <- SPARQL(endpoint, query)
head(resultList[[1]])

                                                                            name staff     lat   long geometry
1 "Hochschule fÃ¼r Angewandte Psychologie der Fachhochschule Nordwestschweiz"@de    80 47.4796 8.2129       NA
2                                                         "Hochschule Luzern"@de  1431 47.0140 8.3060       NA
3                                                                      "AKAD"@de   450      NA     NA       NA
4                                                                      "AKAD"@de  2011      NA     NA       NA
5                                                                      "AKAD"@de  2750      NA     NA       NA
6                                                       "Dar ul-Ulum Deoband"@de   400      NA     NA       NA
```

The problem is, that most of the articles has no information about `lat/long` in the infobox, but are still geotagged as you can see in Wikipedia in the upper right corner as I mentioned. Like 'Fachschule Fulda', it´s the 10th row of the query result, but without lat/long. When you go to [the Wikipedia article](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hochschule_Fulda), you can see the coordinates in the upper right corner.

Comment: What do you mean by "stuff-entry"?

Comment: `SELECT * WHERE {STUFF_ENTRY TRIPLE PATTERN. ?s geo:lat ?lat .  ?s geo:long ?long .}`

Comment: I think I figured it out. Typos are bad news in Q&A. "stuff-entry" is supposed to be "staff-entry". So the geodata is wanted for every entity that has a "Personal staff".

Comment: I´m really sorry for this confusing typo! @TallTed got it right - I´m looking for geodata with a number of employees.

Answer (score 0):

Since I am not sure what you exactly want to retrieve from dbpedia here is a rather general example. In R you can use the package [SPARQL](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/SPARQL/index.html) to send SPARQL queries to endpoints (here the endpoint of dbpedia.org) you are interested in. Here is the code for fetching the label, subject, latitude and longitude of all resources:

```
library(SPARQL)

query <- 
"PREFIX geo: <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#>

SELECT DISTINCT ?label ?subject  ?lat ?long WHERE {
  ?subject geo:lat ?lat.
  ?subject geo:long ?long.
  ?subject rdfs:label ?label.
}"

endpoint <- "http://dbpedia.org/sparql"
resultList <- SPARQL(endpoint, query)
head(results[[1]])

                    label                                          subject     lat     long
1              "大袋駅"@ja    <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Ōbukuro_Station> 35.9244 139.7780
2 "Stazione di Ōbukuro"@it    <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Ōbukuro_Station> 35.9244 139.7780
3              "大袋站"@zh    <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Ōbukuro_Station> 35.9244 139.7780
4     "Ōbukuro Station"@en    <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Ōbukuro_Station> 35.9244 139.7780
5   "111 Murray Street"@en  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/111_Murray_Street> 40.7156 -74.0128
6  "11th Ward, Chicago"@en <http://dbpedia.org/resource/11th_Ward,_Chicago> 41.8380 -87.6460



dim(results[[1]])
[1] 10000     4
```

Note that the number of results is limit to 10000 for one query. So if you want to retrieve more, you have to use `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` like this:

```
query <- 
"PREFIX geo: <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#>

SELECT DISTINCT ?label ?subject  ?lat ?long WHERE {
  ?subject geo:lat ?lat.
  ?subject geo:long ?long.
  ?subject rdfs:label ?label.
} LIMIT 10000 OFFSET 10000"
```

This query would return the results 10001 to 20000!

For details how SPARQL queries work I can refer you to this excellent tutorial: [SPARQL by Example](http://www.cambridgesemantics.com/semantic-university/sparql-by-example)

Comment: Note that results are returned in server-chosen arbitrary order, which may vary with each execution, so you should *always* have an `ORDER BY` when using `LIMIT`+`OFFSET`.

Comment: @Martin Dabbel Ju Smelter: Thanks for the useful hint to use `OFFSET` for a higher number of results! The rest of your code is also my current status, which gives me not the results I´m looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Note that DBpedia data is derived from Wikipedia data, but DBpedia isn't always current with the firehose, so just seeing something on Wikipedia doesn't mean it will be on DBpedia.

I'd start by looking at some of the resources about which you care, in the DBpdia dataset -- to see what attributes they have, and especially, to see which attributes might be what you want.

I think there's more you might be interested in than `lat` and `long`, such as you might see through [a query like this](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&qtxt=++++PREFIX++dbpedia-owl%3A++%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E+%0D%0A++++PREFIX++++++++++geo%3A++%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2003%2F01%2Fgeo%2Fwgs84_pos%23%3E%0D%0A++++PREFIX+++++++georss%3A++%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.georss.org%2Fgeorss%2F%3E%0D%0A++++%0D%0A++++SELECT+DISTINCT+%3Flabel++%3Fsubject++%3Fstaff%0D%0A++++++++++++++++++++%3Flat+%3Flong+%0D%0A++++++++++++++++++++%3Fgeometry+%0D%0A++++++++++++++++++++%3Fgeorss%0D%0A+++++WHERE+%0D%0A+++++++%7B+++++++++++++++%3Fsubject++dbpedia-owl%3Astaff+%3Fstaff+++++++++++%3B%0D%0A+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++rdfs%3Alabel++++++++%3Flabel+++++++++++.%0D%0A+++++++++++OPTIONAL+%7B++%3Fsubject++geo%3Alat+++++++++++%3Flat+++++++++++++.+%7D%0D%0A+++++++++++OPTIONAL+%7B++%3Fsubject++geo%3Along++++++++++%3Flong++++++++++++.+%7D%0D%0A+++++++++++OPTIONAL+%7B++%3Fsubject++georss%3Apoint++++++%3Fgeorss++++++++++.+%7D%0D%0A+++++++++++OPTIONAL+%7B++%3Fsubject++geo%3Ageometry++++++%3Fgeometry++++++++.+%7D%0D%0A++++++++%7D+%0D%0A++++ORDER+BY++%0D%0A++++++++++++++ASC++%28+%3Flat++++++%29+%0D%0A++++++++++++++ASC++%28+%3Flong+++++%29+%0D%0A++++++++++++++ASC++%28+%3Fgeometry+%29+%0D%0A++++++++++++++ASC++%28+%3Fgeorss+++%29%0D%0A++++++++++++++ASC++%28+%3Flabel++++%29%0D%0A++++++++++++++ASC++%28+%3Fsubject++%29%0D%0A+++++++LIMIT++1000+%0D%0A++++++OFFSET++10000&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on) --

```
PREFIX  dbpedia-owl:  <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> 
PREFIX          geo:  <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#>
PREFIX       georss:  <http://www.georss.org/georss/>

SELECT DISTINCT ?label  ?subject  ?staff
                ?lat ?long 
                ?geometry 
                ?georss
 WHERE 
   {               ?subject  dbpedia-owl:staff ?staff           ;
                             rdfs:label        ?label           .
       OPTIONAL {  ?subject  geo:lat           ?lat             . }
       OPTIONAL {  ?subject  geo:long          ?long            . }
       OPTIONAL {  ?subject  georss:point      ?georss          . }
       OPTIONAL {  ?subject  geo:geometry      ?geometry        . }
    } 
ORDER BY  
          ASC  ( ?lat      ) 
          ASC  ( ?long     ) 
          ASC  ( ?geometry ) 
          ASC  ( ?georss   )
          ASC  ( ?label    )
          ASC  ( ?subject  )
   LIMIT  1000 
  OFFSET  10000
```

[LIVE RESULTS](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=++++PREFIX++dbpedia-owl%3A++%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E+%0D%0A++++PREFIX++++++++++geo%3A++%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2003%2F01%2Fgeo%2Fwgs84_pos%23%3E%0D%0A++++PREFIX+++++++georss%3A++%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.georss.org%2Fgeorss%2F%3E%0D%0A++++%0D%0A++++SELECT+DISTINCT+%3Flabel++%3Fsubject++%3Fstaff%0D%0A++++++++++++++++++++%3Flat+%3Flong+%0D%0A++++++++++++++++++++%3Fgeometry+%0D%0A++++++++++++++++++++%3Fgeorss%0D%0A+++++WHERE+%0D%0A+++++++%7B+++++++++++++++%3Fsubject++dbpedia-owl%3Astaff+%3Fstaff+++++++++++%3B%0D%0A+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++rdfs%3Alabel++++++++%3Flabel+++++++++++.%0D%0A+++++++++++OPTIONAL+%7B++%3Fsubject++geo%3Alat+++++++++++%3Flat+++++++++++++.+%7D%0D%0A+++++++++++OPTIONAL+%7B++%3Fsubject++geo%3Along++++++++++%3Flong++++++++++++.+%7D%0D%0A+++++++++++OPTIONAL+%7B++%3Fsubject++georss%3Apoint++++++%3Fgeorss++++++++++.+%7D%0D%0A+++++++++++OPTIONAL+%7B++%3Fsubject++geo%3Ageometry++++++%3Fgeometry++++++++.+%7D%0D%0A++++++++%7D+%0D%0A++++ORDER+BY++%0D%0A++++++++++++++ASC++%28+%3Flat++++++%29+%0D%0A++++++++++++++ASC++%28+%3Flong+++++%29+%0D%0A++++++++++++++ASC++%28+%3Fgeometry+%29+%0D%0A++++++++++++++ASC++%28+%3Fgeorss+++%29%0D%0A++++++++++++++ASC++%28+%3Flabel++++%29%0D%0A++++++++++++++ASC++%28+%3Fsubject++%29%0D%0A+++++++LIMIT++1000+%0D%0A++++++OFFSET++10000&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on)

Comment: Many thanks for your detailed answer to my confusing question. It is right, that there are different attributes to geocode as you mentioned. The problem is, that Wikipedia manage the coordinates for geocodes articles not in the article itself but in another database, hence they doesn´t appear in the source code and consequential not in DBPedia. It´s the same with population data, which is (in Germany) usually not part of the infobox, but automatically insert from official statistical data via IDs.

Comment: In that case, I suggest you raise this wish to the people working on the [DBpdia extractors](https://sourceforge.net/p/dbpedia/mailman/dbpedia-developers/) and/or [DBpedia in general](https://sourceforge.net/p/dbpedia/mailman/dbpedia-discussion/).

Answer (score 0):

I found an awkward solution but it´s working:

1. Download a database with a list of all geocoded articles [here](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:WikiProjekt_Georeferenzierung/Hauptseite/Wikipedia-World/en)
2. Import it into a PostGIS database with this [query](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia_Diskussion:WikiProjekt_Georeferenzierung/Hauptseite/Wikipedia-World/news#Database_Structure_postGIS)
3. Query all records within the area of interest and their Page_ID
4. Query all required records in DBPedia with their wikiPageID
5. Link both datasets in R